# If I cut a 10 second clip into two parts, would the ending time for the first clip be 00:00:05 or 00:00:04 to prevent overlapping?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut a 10 second clip into two parts and then merging the two clips into one using a movie editing software.

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/movie.mp4 -to 00:00:05 -c copy -copyts C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/part1.mp4`

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/movie.mp4 -to 00:00:10 -c copy -copyts C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/part2.mp4`

I'm confused on whether the clip time being cut in the first command should be either
`00:00:05` or `00:00:04` to prevent an overlapping second of a clip because the second command is starting at `00:00:05`. What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `-to 5` on the first and `-ss 5` on the second. However, I prefer using the [`segment` muxer format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) instead:

```
ffmpeg -t 10 -i movie.mp4 \
       -f segment -c copy -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 part%d.mp4
```

Note that because it cuts video at keyframes, you won't get exact 5 second split. If that's necessary, you can try `-break_non_keyframes 1` and see if it works with your manipulation downstream.

Also, I removed `-copyts` option and added `-reset_timestamps 1` so I could watch the segmented video on VLC. Tweak as needed.

There are a lot more options for this muxer. Read the documentation linked above.